# Apache Camel / Azure Vault URI setup

Tags: azure, apache-camel, uri, azure-keyvault

We are having an issue trying to read outlook emails.
Currently we are using the following Apache camel endpoint to login to Outlook 365 emails:

```
imaps://Outlook.office365.com:993?password=XXXX&username=YYYY
```

We upgraded to apache Camel 3.17 to have access to azure vault. We began our testing with tenantId and clientId.

We get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Azure Secret Client or client Id, client secret and tenant Id must be specified at org.apache.camel.component.azure.key.vault.KeyVaultComponent.createEndpoint(KeyVaultComponent.java:66) at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:171) at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doGetEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:951) ... 97 more
```

If anyone has set this up successfully, please help with an example of URI parameters.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by using azure key vault component? You need to specify more parameters to make it works.

Comment: Microsoft is removing simple authentication and soon we will no longer be able to access Outlook with just an ID and Password.
We are hope by adding Authenticator in the endpoint to get a token.

Actually we are not sure what parameters to add to the endpoint to comply with the required Microsoft authentication and we are hoping that Azure Vault could help by providing the token.

Thank you

Comment: As reported in the Apache Camel documentation you need to specify also a client Secret and in the path the vault name where you're storing your secret https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/azure-key-vault-component.html for getting a secret you should have an endpoint like this one https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-azure/camel-azure-key-vault/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/azure/key/vault/integration/operations/KeyVaultOperationsTest.java#L101